# Android Vector Resource Corner with elliptical arc

Tags: android, css, border, androiddesignsupport, android-vectordrawable

`<corners>` inside `<shape>` tag  is used to get **rounded corners** with **circular arc** in vector drawable in android like this :

```
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
    />
```

[image]
 But there does not seem to be an easy solution to get **rounded corners** with **elliptical corners**. which is very easy to do in CSS like this :

```
border-radius: 5px/10px;
```

Is it really impossible to do so without custom `<path>` tag inside `<vector>` or there is easy solution I am not aware of?

Comment: either use `GradientDrawable` or  `RoundRectShape`

Comment: How would I use GradientDrawable to get elliptical corners ? Any reference/example  you can provide on these things ?

Comment: Google android docs does not seem to cover how to use these things

Comment: see [GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) docs on how to set corner radii

Comment: Can we not do that in xml?

Comment: yes, you can not do that in xml

Comment: That is what I was trying to ask, thanks ..